# Is it okay to use Multivariate Multiple Regression on correlated independent and dependent variables?

Tags: correlation, multivariate-regression

I'm confused on this one. So, I'd appreciate it if you could help me explain this a little bit.

So, I have about 15 independent variables and 3 dependent variables. out of these 15 independent variables, 3 are highly correlated with 3 dependent variables (one each). I'm trying to read up on Multivariate Multiple Regression to understand it more. In the meantime, could you please shade some lights on this if it is okay to do it this way if some independent variables are correlated with dependent variables?

Comment: If the dependent variables were not correlated with any independent variables (or any of their linear combinations), why would you even be attempting regression in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as @whuber commented, these correlations are exactly what will make the model work. So for example, height is correlated with weight, so if you want to predict weight, and have height as a predictor, it's going to be a good predictor.

There is sometimes a problem with correlations. That happens when independent variables, predictors, are correlated with each other. For example, when you predict height (H) with left leg length (LL) and right leg lenght (RL). Then the model

$$
H \sim a + b * LL + c * RL + \epsilon
$$

Will become problematic. The problem is that the model can exchange `a` and `b`, and the model becomes unidentifiable, or close to it. You might lose significance of both leg lenghts, while they are clearly very good predictors of height, or you can get crazy estimates like

$$
H = 0 + 250 * LL - 248 * RL
$$

which actually makes sense, because you are approximately twice as long as your legs (that's very approximate..), and that's pretty much what this formula then says, because $LL \approx RL$, but the individual coefficients dont' make sense at all.